# Change columns of a table in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a large table in WordPress, I need to change the order of the columns, but I have to do it manually every time, when I need. Is there any plugin out there, in which all table loads up and I drag and drop the whole column from there as my choice?

The website is [here](https://lineup2020.com)

Comment: you can custom code it with jQuery UI draggable

Comment: but on page refresh it will reset, how to save the order of the table in database?

Comment: create a json tree structure of the table and save as string to database. On page load take this string and decode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, i can give you a demo to show you how to move forward with your requirements.

Please check this [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/melvin007/oa74h1vr/2/). As you requested we are using [Dragtable js](https://github.com/akottr/dragtable).

Once sorting is completed we checks each row of the table finds each column of the respective row and create a json tree structure.

Html

```
<table id="sort_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="draggable">Col1</th>
      <th class="draggable">Col2</th>
      <th class="draggable">Col3</th>
      <th class="draggable">Col4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row1</td>
      <td>Data11</td>
      <td>Data12</td>
      <td>Data13</td>
      <td>Data14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row2</td>
      <td>Data21</td>
      <td>Data22</td>
      <td>Data23</td>
      <td>Data24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row3</td>
      <td>Data31</td>
      <td>Data32</td>
      <td>Data33</td>
      <td>Data34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row4</td>
      <td>Data41</td>
      <td>Data42</td>
      <td>Data43</td>
      <td>Data44</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS (**UPDATED**)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sort_table').dragtable({
    dragaccept: '.draggable',
    beforeStop: function() {
      var tree = {};
      var rows = [];
      $('#sort_table tr').each(function() {
        var col_count = 0;
        var cols = [];
        $(this).children().each(function() {
          cols[col_count] = $(this).html();
          col_count++;
        });
        rows.push(cols);
      });
      tree.data = rows;
      var tree_json = JSON.stringify(tree); // use the variable to save to DB
      console.log(tree_json);
    }
  });
});
```

You can save the variable **tree_json** to database (Call ajax to php and save to DB)

On each page load you could take the value from database to a variable and using json_decode to make the string a json object

```
$table_structure  = ; // Code to take from db
$table_structure = json_decode($table_structure);
```

You can copy and paste json from console to check if its valid using [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: I need to move columns not rows.

Comment: You can use jQuery plugins for that. This is an exmple to show how you should save table data

Comment: can you help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432674/jquery-dragtable-js-not-working-with-large-table)

Comment: @InYourFace Ok thanks for the link . Will update the answer soon

Comment: @InYourFace I have updated my code and jsfiddle. Please check it

Comment: @InYourFace Is it working ? Please mark it as answer and upvote for my effort :)

Comment: I'm trying it's working can you tell me one last thing how can I apply it on page refresh? and I'm going to accept it.

Comment: @InYourFace if you place the `js` code in your code, each time when you sort columns a json tree structure is created. So you can send the data to php via ajax and save to database. Instead of writing the table in html take the saved value from database and loop it to create a table structure. Show me some sample code and i will help you

Comment: Bro my last row miss aligns don't know why it's happening.

Comment: please post a screenshot.

Comment: I'm making a gif so that you can easily understand please wait.

Comment: I have uploaded [here](https://gifyu.com/image/3UI0), check it. The main issue is that when I work with last row it makes miss-alignments. Can you fixed that up?

Comment: In the [documentation](https://akottr.github.io/dragtable/), see last example can't you setup that one? because it's a lot more easier with that one, I have tried but that's not working, I have also asked a question here, but no answer there can you also help there? The question link is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432674/jquery-dragtable-js-not-working-with-large-table)

Comment: You have a fixed footer ?

Comment: No I have fixed header on scroll but footer is simple also this happens when I move last column otherwise it's working fine.

Comment: the last code is no different than what i have implied. I don't know why is that happening . Can you post a fiddle or something like that ?

Comment: It's wordpress how can I post?

Comment: @InYourFace the problem is not due to code. Something else if you can post the html, styles and js in a fiddle, i can have a look

Comment: can you tell me how to build up table on page load? I am unable to build up.

Comment: can you tell me what have you tried so far to build a table ?